# How can I change language settings in android studio on a button click.

Tags: java, android

I only want to change the language in the app. I also want to know how to set a default strings.xml file as main language.

I have seen lots of questions like mine on the internet, but they seem to be a bit outdated.

Comment: You can change but it is not advisable to change the language inside a app different from the phone language and second thing if you haven't declared string resource for different languages android will only take the String resource that is available

Answer (score 0):

by this define your default language when it starts

```
        Configuration mainConfig = new Configuration(getResources().getConfiguration());
    String languageToLoad = "en";
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    mainConfig.setLocale(locale);
    getResources().updateConfiguration(mainConfig, null);
```

and you can change it again and save selected language in shared preferences

```
        new SharedPreferencesUtils(this).setPreferenceStrings("selected_language", "en");
```

Comment: any time you enter your application you can check shared preferences and set selected language